# What part of speech is the word 'to' used before verb infinitives?

Tags: prepositions

E.g. to write, to ask, to come and so on.

Can it be considered a preposition in this situation? I know many languages allow prepositions before verbs. If it isn't a preposition, then I wonder what part of speech it can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its part of speech is not preposition but 'subordinator', and its function  in the clause is 'marker'.

It's just "write", "ask" and "come" that are the  verbs.

Note that the subordinator "to" derives historically from the preposition "to", but long ago lost its prepositional properties.